# "Access denied" in python serial library

Tags: python, serial-port, access-denied, micropython

Hello I am new at coding the microcontrolers and I dont know what I am doing wrong. Could someone help me. I get the access denied. I checked everything the port, baudrate, drivers and still get this error. I dont have more ideas
CODE IN PYTHON

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pyaudio
import webbrowser
import os
import subprocess
import serial

silnik = pyttsx3.init()
silnik.setProperty("glosnosc", 0.70)
silnik.setProperty("szybkosc", 120)
voices = silnik.getProperty('voices')
silnik.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
przegladarka_path = "C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera GX/launcher.exe %s"
num = 5

ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 115200)
ser.open()

def recognise(msg="Powiedz coś!"):
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print(msg)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            recognised_text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="pl-PL")
            print("Powiedziałeś: " + recognised_text)
            return recognised_text.lower()
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Nie rozumiem co mowisz")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("ERROR", e)


text = recognise()
word_list = text.split(" ")
if ("otwórz" in text and word_list[0] == "otwórz") or ("uruchom" in text and word_list[0] == "uruchom"):
    if "przeglądarkę" in text:
        silnik.say("Otwieram przeglądarke!")
        silnik.runAndWait()
        webbrowser.get(przegladarka_path).open_new_tab("http://www.google.com")

    if "youtube" in text:
        silnik.say("Otwieram YouTube!")
        silnik.runAndWait()
        webbrowser.get(przegladarka_path).open_new_tab("https://www.youtube.com")

    if "diskord" or "discord" in text:
        silnik.say("Otwieram discorda!")
        silnik.runAndWait()
        os.startfile("C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Discord/app-1.0.9013/Discord.exe")

if "wyłącz" in text and word_list[0] == "wyłącz":
    if "komputer" in text:
        silnik.say(f"Wyłączam komputer za {num} sekund")
        os.system(f"shutdown /s /t {num}")
    if "led" in text:
        ser.write(encode("OFF"))

if "włącz" in text and word_list[0] == "włącz":
    if "led" in text:
        ser.write(encode("ON"))
```

CODE IN MICROPYTHON

```
import machine
import time

led_pin = machine.Pin(16, machine.Pin.OUT)
uart = machine.UART(0, 115200)

while True:
    if uart.any():
        command = uart.read().decode().strip()
        print("Otrzymane polecenie: " + command)

        if command == "ON":
            led_pin.on()
        elif command == "OFF":
            led_pin.off()

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

and I get the access denied. I checked everything the port, baudrate, drivers and still get this error.